# $(a,m) = (b,m) = 1 \overset{?}{\implies} (ab,m) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In words, is this saying that since $a$ shares no common prime factors with $m$ and $b$ shares no common prime factors with $m$ too, then of course the product of $a$ and $b$ wouldn't either!?

Comment: This is a true implication - is that what you're asking? It would be proved in any number theory textbook.

Comment: @GregMartin Is that right? **Any** number theory textbook? You know, Greg Martin, I think you're wrong. I bet there is a number theory textbook out there that actually doesn't have it. What do you think? You think I'm right?

Comment: I'm asking, as my question mark should allude to, exactly what I wrote as a question in this post.

Comment: I would say your interpretation is correct.

Comment: I suspect, however, that algebraic symbolism is required to "prove" this though.

Comment: Do you know Euclid's algorithm?

Comment: @user69819 See my answer.

Comment: @GregMartin See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$
(a b,m)=d
$, then by definition of GCD we have that $d|a b$ and $d|m$. Since $d|a b$, it is necessary that $d|a$ or $d|b$ because if   $d\nmid a$ and $d\nmid b$ then it wouldn't be true that $d|a b$, thus we have $d|a$ or $d|b$ and by this we can deduce that $d|a$ and $d|m$, or $d|b$ and $d|m$. By hypothesis we know that $(a,m)=(b,m)=1$ so by properties of the GCD we have that $d|(a,m)=1$ or $d|(b,m)=1$ and thus $d=1$.

Comment: Except $6 \not\mid 3$ and $6 \not\mid 4$, but $6 \mid 3\cdot 4$. However, if $d$ is prime, this holds.

Comment: As @HenrySwanson's comment shows, your proof is only correct if you change your first line from "Suppose $(ab, m) = d$" to something like "Suppose $d$ is a prime dividing both $ab$ and $m$".

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking something like this:

Let $p_{1}^{e_1}p_{2}^{e_2}p_{3}^{e_3}\cdots$ be the prime factorization of $a$, and let $p_{1}^{f_1}p_{2}^{f_2}p_{3}^{f_3}\cdots$ be the prime factorization of $b$, and let $p_{1}^{g_1}p_{2}^{g_2}p_{3}^{g_3}\cdots$ be the prime factorization of $m$. Hence, if $(a,m)=(b,m)=1$, then for no $i=j$ is $p_{i}=p_{j}$ for all $i$'s of $a$ and all $j$'s of $b$. Similarly, for no $j=k$ is $p_{j}=p_{k}$ for all $j$'s of $a$ and all $k$'s of $b$. Thus it is plain that a scan through $a$ and $b$'s prime factors not matching with any in $m$'s will not produce a match in $a$ and $b$'s product.

Comment: @JosephG. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bezout's Identity is helpful with problems like this. If $a$ and $b$ are integers, and $\gcd(a,b)=d$, then there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that: $$ax+by=d$$ Since the OP already posted his solution, I'll post one using Bezout's identity. Since $\gcd(a,m)=1$, by Bezout there exists integers $x_1$ and $y_1$ such that $$ax_1+my_1=1.$$Similarly, since $\gcd(b,m)=1$, there exist integers $x_2$ and $y_2$ such that $$bx_2+my_2=1.$$ Multiplying these two equations yields $$(ax_1+my_1)(bx_2+my_2)=1\cdot 1 $$ $$ \Longrightarrow abx_1x_2+m(ay_2+by_1+my_1y_2)=1.$$Let $x_3=x_1x_2$ and $y_3=ay_2+by_1+my_1y_2$ Then our new equation is: $$abx_3+my_3=1.$$ Note that the $\gcd(ab,m)$ divides $ab$ and it divides $m$, which implies it divides the LHS of this equation. Hence it divides 1, which shows us $\gcd(ab,m)=1$.

Comment: I may be noted that this is basically the first argument of the answer by N. S. spelled out: $x_1$ represents the inverse of $a$ modulo $m$, while $x_2$ represents the inverse of $b$ modulo $m$; to find an inverse of the product $ab$ modulo $m$, just multiply the inverses. In other words, multiplying the congruences $ax_1\equiv1$ and $bx_2\equiv1$ gives $abx_1x_2\equiv1$, all this modulo$~m$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(a,m)=1$ then $a$ has an inverse $a^{-1} \pmod m$.

Since $(b,m)=1$ then $b$ has an inverse $b^{-1} \pmod m$.

But then $a^{-1}b^{-1} \pmod m$ is the inverse of $ab \pmod m$. Thus, since $ab$ is invertible, $(ab,m)=1$.

**Alternately** If $d\mid ab, \ d\mid m$. Now $(a,d)\mid(a,m)=1$ thus $(a,d)=1$.

Now, $d\mid ab, (a,d)=1 \Rightarrow d\mid b$.

Hence $d\mid b, d\mid m \Rightarrow d\mid(b,m)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$1. (a,m)=1 = (b,m) \implies a $ and $b$ have no common factors with $m$, the product of them also is a complete composition of $a$ and $b$, therefore $ab$ has no common factors $m \implies ab$ and $m$ are coprimes..